# How to configure Spring-Boot MyBatis to look for XML mappers in class folder/directory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I have a large Spring + MyBatis app that I'm trying to convert to a Spring-Boot + MyBatis AWS Lambda (+ layers) function. I'm trying to do this in small steps based on https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-03/springboot-mybatis-mysql/#gsc.tab=0.

Essentially, I want to move the XML mappers to wherever the corresponding java mapper resides (same as in my original app, which, for whatever reason, works fine):

[image: Move XML mapper to where Java mapper resides]

However, I just can't seem to configure MyBatis to work when I move the XML mapper. I tried the following settings in the application.yml file but to no avail:

```
server:
  port: 9090
  
...

mybatis:
  mapper-locations: classpath:mapper/**/*-mapper.xml                    # OK with mapper under .../resources/mapper
#  mapper-locations: classpath:**/*-mapper.xml                          # OK with mapper under .../resources/mapper
#  mapper-locations: classpath:**/*-mapper.xml                          # NOT OK with mapper under io/springcloud/.../mapper
#  mapper-locations: classpath:io/springcloud/mybatis/**/*-mapper.xml   # NOT OK with mapper under io/springcloud/.../mapper
```

If I move the XML mapper, it typically fails like this when I run mvn install:

```
...
2022-08-08 14:57:30.673  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@52f27fbd testClass = ApplicationTest, testInstance = io.springcloud.test.ApplicationTest@6f204a1a, testMethod = test@ApplicationTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4c163e3 testClass = ApplicationTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class io.springcloud.mybatis.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6b19b79, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@75f32542, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@27ae2fd0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@15b204a1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@419c5f1a, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@4d49af10], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> false, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager@3d24420b]; rollback [false]
2022-08-08 14:57:31.742  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Committed transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@52f27fbd testClass = ApplicationTest, testInstance = io.springcloud.test.ApplicationTest@6f204a1a, testMethod = test@ApplicationTest, testException = org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): io.springcloud.mybatis.mapper.FooMapper.now, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4c163e3 testClass = ApplicationTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class io.springcloud.mybatis.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6b19b79, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@75f32542, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@27ae2fd0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@15b204a1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@419c5f1a, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@4d49af10], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> false, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.632 s <<< FAILURE! - in io.springcloud.test.ApplicationTest
[ERROR] test  Time elapsed: 1.701 s  <<< ERROR!
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): io.springcloud.mybatis.mapper.FooMapper.now
    at io.springcloud.test.ApplicationTest.test(ApplicationTest.java:35)

2022-08-08 14:57:31.856  INFO 13716 --- [ionShutdownHook] io.undertow                              : stopping server: Undertow - 2.2.16.Final
2022-08-08 14:57:31.885  INFO 13716 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-08-08 14:57:31.922  INFO 13716 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   ApplicationTest.test:35 » Binding Invalid bound statement (not found): io.spri...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using mybatis-spring-boot, you should let it auto-scan Java mappers. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/). Note that XML file should be in the same path as the corresponding Java mapper i.e. `src/main/resources/io/springcloud/mapper/FooMapper.xml`. Off-topic: you should not use `io.springcloud` package for your own project.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check whether the namespace of foo-mapper.xml is the value of FooMapper package name. See below screeshot:

foo-mapper.xml

[image: 1]

FooMapper.java

[image: 2]